# Python bulk insert to Teradata? Default is too slow

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, teradata

I was asked for a Python script to read a file, load into a dataframe, and write to a table in Teradata. It works but it takes 3-4 minutes to write a table that's 300 rows.

Now that's a tiny job for a data warehouse, and our Teradata works fine when handling massive data sets, but I find it's such a drag waiting 3 minutes for this script to run. I don't believe it's a system issue.

Is there a better way to load small to medium size tables into Teradata? If we did this in SQL Server it would take seconds but some other data we need to access is already there in Teradata.

The main code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn_string = 'teradata://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + '/?authentication=LDAP'
eng = create_engine(conn_string)

# insert into table
df.to_sql(table_name, con = eng, if_exists = 'replace', 
          schema='TEMP', index=False, dtype=df_datatypes)
```

The above works but when I added the method='multi' parameter to to_sql, I got the error:

```
    CompileError: The 'teradata' dialect with current database version settings does not 
support in-place multirow inserts.
```

Then I added chunksize=100 and I got this error:

```
DatabaseError: [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-9719)QVCI feature is disabled.
```

Is there a way to speed this up? Should I do something outside of Python altogether?

Comment: The 2nd error is not related to the chunksize. Update to the latest Teradata driver version, this should fix it.

Comment: Or consider using _teradatasql_ dialect (_teradatasqlalchemy_ package), instead of _teradata_ dialect (_sqlalchemy-teradata_ package)+ ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedro, if you are trying to load one row at a time through ODBC, you are approaching the problem like trying to fill a swimming pool through a straw.

Teradata is and has always been a parallel platform. You need to use bulk loaders—or, if you are a Python fan, use teradataml (code below).

By the way, I loaded 728,000 records in 12 seconds on my laptop. When I built a Teradata system in Azure, I was able using the same code below to load the same 728,000 records in 2 seconds:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from teradataml import create_context, remove_context
con = create_context(host = <host name or IP address>, username=<username>, password=<password>, database='<#what ever default database you want>')

colnames = ['storeid','custnumber','invoicenumber','amount']

dataDF = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv', delimiter=',', names=colnames, header=None)

copy_to_sql(dataDF, table_name = 'store', if_exists='replace') # this will load the datafrom from your client machine into the Teradata system.

remove_context()
```

Answer (score 0):

pedro. I can empathize with you. I work at an organization that has massive data warehouses in Teradata and it's next to impossible to get it to work well. I developed a Python (3.9) script that uses the `teradatasql` package to interface Python/SQLAlchemy and it works reasonably well.

This script reflects a PostgreSQL database and, table-by-table, pulls the data from PostgreSQL, saves it as an object in Python and then uses the reflected PostgreSQL tables to create comparable versions in Teradata and finally push the retrieved data to the tables.

I've quality checked this and here's what I get:

- table reflection time in PostgreSQL: 0.95 seconds on average
- longest PostgreSQL data retrieval: 4.22 seconds
- *shortest* time to create mirrored tables in Teradata: 12.10 seconds
- *shortest* time to load data to Teradata: 8.39 seconds
- *longest* time to load data to Teradata: approx. 7,212 seconds

The point here is Teradata is a miserable platform that's ill equipped for business critical tasks. I've demonstrated to senior leadership the performance of Teradata against 5 other ODBC's and Teradata was far and away the least capable.

Maybe things are better on version 17; however, we're on version 16.20.53.30 which also doesn't support in-place multirow inserts. I'd recommend your organization stop using Teradata and move to something more capable, like Snowflake. Snowflake has EXCELLENT Python support and a great CLI.